# Is there a way to limit maxdepth for ls -Rhal?

Tags: linux, bash, ls

Is there a way to limit maxdepth in a `ls -Rhal` command? I am aware of `find . -maxdepth`, but I want to be able to get the file information that comes with `ls -Rhal`.

Comment: Will `find . -maxdepth 2 -type d -print0 | xargs -0 ls -hal` help you?

Comment: Yes thank you. Looks like I need to dive deeper into the man pages next time.

Answer (score 2):

These might help:

1. Use `find`'s `-printf`, this will give the size of files in Kb, so not quite `ls -lh`:

   ```
   find . -maxdepth 2 -printf '%M %n %u %g %kK %Tc %p\n'
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   drwxr-xr-x 4 terdon terdon 140K Tue 25 Jun 2013 04:52:17 PM CEST .
   -rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 64K Mon 24 Jun 2013 03:46:05 PM CEST ./foo.pdf
   drwxr-xr-x 2 terdon terdon 4K Tue 25 Jun 2013 03:10:22 PM CEST ./hho
   -rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 0K Tue 25 Jun 2013 03:10:22 PM CEST ./hho/b
   drwxr-xr-x 3 terdon terdon 4K Tue 25 Jun 2013 04:23:29 PM CEST ./haha
   drwxr-xr-x 3 terdon terdon 4K Tue 25 Jun 2013 04:24:05 PM CEST ./haha/hoho
   -rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 0K Tue 25 Jun 2013 03:10:16 PM CEST ./haha/a
   ```

   Explanation:

   > -printf format

   ```
         %M     File's permissions (in  symbolic  form,
                as  for  ls).   This  directive is sup‐
                ported in findutils 4.2.5 and later.
         %n     Number of hard links to file.
         %u     File's user name, or numeric user ID if
                the user has no name.
         %g     File's  group name, or numeric group ID
                if the group has no name.
         %k     The  amount of disk space used for this
                file in 1K blocks. Since disk space  is
                allocated  in multiples of the filesys‐
                tem block size this is usually  greater
                than   %s/1024,  but  it  can  also  be
                smaller if the file is a sparse file.
         %Tk    File's last modification  time  in  the
                format  specified  by  k,  which is the
                same as for %A.

                c      locale's  date and time (Sat Nov
                       04 12:02:33 EST 1989).  The for‐
                       mat  is the same as for ctime(3)
                       and so to preserve compatibility
                       with  that  format,  there is no
                       fractional part in  the  seconds
                       field.
         %p     File's name.
   ```
2. Use `find`'s `-ls` option:

   ```
   find . -maxdepth 2 -ls
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   16728263  140 drwxr-xr-x   4 terdon terdon   143360 Jun 25 16:52 .
   16719778   64 -rw-r--r--   1 terdon   terdon      65465 Jun 24 15:46 ./foo.pdf
   16744471    4 drwxr-xr-x   2 terdon   terdon       4096 Jun 25 15:10 ./hho
   16723388    0 -rw-r--r--   1 terdon   terdon          0 Jun 25 15:10 ./hho/b
   16744470    4 drwxr-xr-x   3 terdon   terdon       4096 Jun 25 16:23 ./haha
   16744472    4 drwxr-xr-x   3 terdon   terdon       4096 Jun 25 16:24 ./haha/hoho
   16719491    0 -rw-r--r--   1 terdon   terdon          0 Jun 25 15:10 ./haha/a
   ```

   Explanation:

   ```
   -ls    True;  list current file in ls -dils format on
         standard output.  The block counts are  of  1K
         blocks,   unless   the   environment  variable
         POSIXLY_CORRECT is set, in which case 512-byte
         blocks  are  used.   See the UNUSUAL FILENAMES
         section  for  information  about  how  unusual
         characters in filenames are handled.
   ```
3. Use [@mpy](https://superuser.com/users/195224/mpy)'s suggestion (this is probably the best solution):

   ```
   find . -maxdepth 2 -type d -print0 | xargs -0 ls -hal
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   .:
   total 696K
   drwxr-xr-x   4 terdon terdon 140K Jun 25 16:56 .
   drwxr-xr-x 141 terdon terdon 480K Jun 25 16:25 ..
   -rw-r--r--   1 terdon terdon    0 Jun 25 16:56 a
   -rw-r--r--   1 terdon   terdon    64K Jun 24 15:46 foo.pdf
   drwxr-xr-x   3 terdon   terdon   4.0K Jun 25 16:23 haha
   drwxr-xr-x   2 terdon   terdon   4.0K Jun 25 15:10 hho

   ./haha:
   total 148K
   drwxr-xr-x 3 terdon   terdon   4.0K Jun 25 16:23 .
   drwxr-xr-x 4 terdon terdon 140K Jun 25 16:56 ..
   -rw-r--r-- 1 terdon   terdon      0 Jun 25 15:10 a
   drwxr-xr-x 3 terdon   terdon   4.0K Jun 25 16:24 hoho

   ./haha/hoho:
   total 12K
   drwxr-xr-x 3 terdon terdon 4.0K Jun 25 16:24 .
   drwxr-xr-x 3 terdon terdon 4.0K Jun 25 16:23 ..
   -rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon    0 Jun 25 16:23 ha
   drwxr-xr-x 2 terdon terdon 4.0K Jun 25 16:24 hihi

   ./hho:
   total 144K
   drwxr-xr-x 2 terdon   terdon   4.0K Jun 25 15:10 .
   drwxr-xr-x 4 terdon terdon 140K Jun 25 16:56 ..
   -rw-r--r-- 1 terdon   terdon      0 Jun 25 15:10 b
   ```
4. Use `find`'s ' -exec` option:

   ```
   find . -maxdepth 2 -exec ls -hal '{}' \;
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   total 696K
   drwxr-xr-x   4 terdon terdon 140K Jun 25 16:56 .
   drwxr-xr-x 141 terdon terdon 480K Jun 25 16:25 ..
   -rw-r--r--   1 terdon terdon    0 Jun 25 16:59 a
   -rw-r--r--   1 terdon   terdon    64K Jun 24 15:46 foo.pdf
   drwxr-xr-x   3 terdon   terdon   4.0K Jun 25 16:23 haha
   drwxr-xr-x   2 terdon   terdon   4.0K Jun 25 15:10 hho
   -rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 64K Jun 24 15:46 ./foo.pdf
   total 144K
   drwxr-xr-x 2 terdon   terdon   4.0K Jun 25 15:10 .
   drwxr-xr-x 4 terdon terdon 140K Jun 25 16:56 ..
   -rw-r--r-- 1 terdon   terdon      0 Jun 25 15:10 b
   -rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 0 Jun 25 15:10 ./hho/b
   -rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 0 Jun 25 16:59 ./a
   total 148K
   drwxr-xr-x 3 terdon   terdon   4.0K Jun 25 16:23 .
   drwxr-xr-x 4 terdon terdon 140K Jun 25 16:56 ..
   -rw-r--r-- 1 terdon   terdon      0 Jun 25 15:10 a
   drwxr-xr-x 3 terdon   terdon   4.0K Jun 25 16:24 hoho
   total 12K
   drwxr-xr-x 3 terdon terdon 4.0K Jun 25 16:24 .
   drwxr-xr-x 3 terdon terdon 4.0K Jun 25 16:23 ..
   -rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon    0 Jun 25 16:23 ha
   drwxr-xr-x 2 terdon terdon 4.0K Jun 25 16:24 hihi
   -rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 0 Jun 25 15:10 ./haha/a
   ```

   Explanation:

   ```
   -exec command ; 
         Execute command; true if 0 status is returned.
         All following arguments to find are taken to be
         arguments to the command until an argument consisting of
         `;' is encountered.  The string `{}' is replaced by the
         current file name being processed everywhere it occurs
         in the arguments to the command, not just in arguments
         where it is alone, as in some versions of find.  Both of
         these constructions might need to be escaped (with a
         `\') or quoted to protect them from expansion by the
         shell.  See the EXAMPLES section for examples of the use
         of the -exec option.  The specified command is run once
         for each matched file.  The command is executed in the
         starting directory.  There are unavoidable security
         problems surrounding use of the -exec action; you should
         use the -execdir option instead.
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the expanded selections and explanations. Can you explain from an under the hood perspective what the difference is between using the exec and the xargs options?

Comment: @Aaron, not much really. Only that `xargs` will optimize the commands so as to launch as few `ls` instances as possible, it won't really make a difference for what you are trying to do.