# How to show a warning message when entering a folder?

Tags: linux, centos

I don't know if this is possible, but, I have a folder which I would like to show some warning message when the user enters in it.
In my case would say that the folder could be deleted without previous warning to save some disk space.
I already create a file inside the folder with the warning message:

```
WARNING!
##########################################################################################################################################################
Please, 
be advised, that the folder /company-backup/amazon-s3 can be deleted without previous WARNING to save disk space as the INFRASTRUCTURE TEAM judge necessary.

Best regards,
Infrastructure Team.
###########################################################################################################################################################
```

Is that possible ? Any idea ?

Comment: The user enters this folder inside a shell session? (Or via FTP?) Is the shell used identical for all users? With `zsh` you can simply use `chpwd () { [[ -e .readme ]] && cat .readme }`. `chpwd` is called whenever the current working dir is changed, `.readme` is of course your message. This should be doable in other shells, too. In the worst case by redefining `cd`.

Comment: @mpy that's the [second good answer](http://superuser.com/q/611534/151431) you have given as a comment in the last 24h, why don't you write these up as answers?

Comment: @terdon: Because I'm too lazy `;)`. With some more infos from the OP here, I think about writing an answer because I use this per-folder reminder heavily myself.

Comment: @mpy, your loss, I just stole your comment in my answer in the linked post :). You should be able to do this micely for both `bash` and `zsh` if you set `cd` to be an alias to the function you suggested.

Comment: @terdon: Haha, I'm fine with that -- you did a good job. Btw. Oliver Salzburg made a really good comment on that topic on meta (http://meta.superuser.com/a/6830/195224).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is one possibility, if your users access the directory via command line:

Redefine the shell's builtin `cd` command in a global `rc` file to check if a file `.readme` is present in the current dir and if so, display it (with some nice optical elements).

**a.** With `zsh` (`/etc/zshrc`) you can use a specially designed hook function (`chpwd`), which is called whenever the current working dir is changed:

```
function chpwd {
  if [[ -e .readme ]]; then
    echo
    echo \#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#
    cat .readme
    echo \#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#
    echo
fi }
```

**b.** I don't know if there's a similar possibility in `bash`, however you can redefine `cd` in `/etc/bash.bashrc`:

```
cd() {
   builtin cd "$@"
   if [[ -e .readme ]]; then
     echo
     echo \#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#
     cat .readme
     echo \#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#\#
     echo
   fi
}
```

**c.** And finally the same with `csh` (`/etc/csh.cshrc`) syntax:

```
alias cd 'cd \!*; eval "if (-e .readme) then \\
  echo \\
  echo ################################################################################ \\
  cat .readme \\
  echo ################################################################################ \\
  echo \\
endif"'
```

---

And this it how it looks like:

```
user@machine:~> cd temp

################################################################################
Attention! This is a temporary directory!
################################################################################

user@machine:~/temp>
```

Comment: Ah, this is a cool alternative method to what I used in my answer! I didn't notice that you added a bash and csh method as well.

Answer (score 2):

Use [inotify-tools](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki#wiki-info):

> $ inotifywait -e open YOUR_DIRECTORY

Example:

```
$ inotifywait -e open for_delete
Setting up watches.  
Watches established.
for_delete/ OPEN,ISDIR
$
```

There is good example of script in link above.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion regarding zsh was good, but if you want to do something for bash, you might need to script that yourself. I hooked into the `cd` command in bash for a different purpose (so it would display PWD in the title of the terminal window) but the same technique could be used to cat a `.readme` file whenever you `cd` into a directory.

All I did was write a script to perform the `cd` (using the `builtin` keyword to allow me to overwrite the actual command--you could also use `\cd`) and also do whatever operation I wished after it completed. I stored the script in my home directory somewhere (I like `~/scripts`, personally), and then created an alias in my `.bashrc` file that sources it.

This is how it looks for me. For your case, instead of the `echo` command, you would want to `cat $PWD/.readme`.

~/scripts/cd.sh:

```
builtin cd $1
echo -ne "\033]0;$shell_title - `pwd | sed "s|$HOME|~|g"`\007"
```

~/.bashrc:

```
alias cd='source ~/scripts/cd.sh'
```

Now, whenever I type `cd` into the terminal, it will source that script, changing directory and my window title.